# Optimizing/designing table structure and relationship

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-design

I have three tables:

```
Campus
Building
Floor
```

and table structure is looks like this:

```
CampusId
CampusDesc

BuildingId
BuildingDesc

FloorId
FloorDesc
```

I need help in optimizing the table relationship. If the user selects Campus then related building should be reference and floor:

> Campus=>Building=>Floor

Do I need a another table for this relationship? Do I need to combine all three?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add CampusId to the table Building as well as BuildingID to the table Floor, that'll establish the links.

In addition, I'ld created indexes on those added fields to speed up future searches.
I would assume that you already have unique indexes on CampusID, BuildingID and FloorID.

Comment: i thought of doing the exact same way but if do that then dont you think the Building table is depend on Campus table and etc..?

Comment: But isn't that the case? Every building belongs to exactly one campus?

Comment: @AbuHamzah: Why would that be bad?

Comment: @Adam: i did not say bad but i wanted to make all three tables (campus,bld,floor) independent of each other and create a new table that have relationship... just throwing ideas.... thats what triggers me to post the question and wanted to see what other folks thinks.

Comment: @AbuHamzah: But why would you want them to be independent? The nature of what they represent creates a natural dependency. Any effort to remove it will be artificial and will leave you with a less-than-ideal data model.